# Почему Java не понимает условие?

Tags: java

```java
 System.out.println("Все верно?(y/n)");
 Scanner answ = new Scanner(System.in);

if (answ.nextLine() == "y")
   System.out.println("Ok");
if (answ.nextLine() == "n")
    System.out.println("Try again");
else
    System.out.println("Неверный ввод(y/n)");
```

Выдает:

Все верно?(y/n)

y // Пишу 'y'

y // Но он опять пытается считать ввод, ввожу опять 'y'

Неверный ввод(y/n) //И в итоге выводит это

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы сравниваете строки оператором `==`, когда это нужно делать с помощью метода `equals()`.

```java
string1.equals(string2);
```

Оператор `==` сравнивает не объекты, а ссылки на них, если это не примитивные типы.

Второй оператор `if` у вас не связан с первым посредством `else`.

Также вы не сохранили значение считанной строки, вместо этого вы вызвали метод `nextLine()` для каждого оператора `if`, из-за чего второе условие не срабатывает, если ввести "n", а просит сделать ввод ещё раз.

Исправленный код будет выглядеть так:

```java
System.out.println("Все верно?(y/n)");
Scanner answ = new Scanner(System.in);

String answer = answ.nextLine();
if (answer.equals("y"))
   System.out.println("Ok");
else if (answer.equals("n"))
    System.out.println("Try again");
else
    System.out.println("Неверный ввод(y/n)");
```

Comment: Спасибо, не знал про этот метод

Comment: @Dolphin это метод класса `Object`, который наследуют все классы в `java`. Он есть не только в строках, но и в других классах, объекты которых создаются. По-хорошему, его всегда надо переопределять в классах, которые вы пишите сами.

Comment: Правда теперь когда ввожу 'n' он опять считывает ввод заново и если опять ввести 'n' то пишет заветный Try again. Так почему с первого раза не работает понять не могу?

Comment: А, ну да, сейчас дополню.

Comment: @Dolphin вот это `answ.nextLine()` - считывание строки с консоли. Посчитайте, сколько раз вы это делаете в своем коде.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо